# Determine last modified date of folders by scanning their subfolders

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder containing many subfolders.

I'm trying to write a function that scans the entire folder and returns the name of each subfolder along with the last modified date.

```
import os,time

def get_information(directory):
    file_list = []
    for i in os.listdir(directory):
        a = os.stat(os.path.join(directory,i))
        file_list.append([i, time.ctime(a.st_atime)])
    return file_list
```

The above works, but I actually want it to to consider all subfolders and files when determining the last modified date.

For example when I look into the folder I'm scanning, I can see one folder called '20050'. The last modified date is 2021/09/09. However, when I go into that folder, I can see files and folders in there which were modified in 2022/01/01.

Not sure why this is, and struggling to write any code that'll scan these subfolders to determine last modified date.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `os.walk`generates the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree:

```
def get_information(directory):
    file_list = []
    for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            a = os.stat(os.path.join(root, file))
            file_list.append([file, time.ctime(a.st_atime)])
    return file_list

print(get_information("C:"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that may work. Although I'm noticing there are a lot of subdirectories so not sure it'll even run. I may need to refactor it to only look at the first or second set of folder/files, and not go any further down the tree.